# login button entry activity even if the password is wrong , Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

im doing user login whit retrofit 2, it works but the problem in on the response, even if the credencials are wrong, it goes to other activity,im using php, the register is working fine, and i have no idea why its going to the other activity. pls any help would be great

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText editTextEmail, editTextPassword;
private Button buttonSignIn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    buttonSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
    buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void userSignIn() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Signing Up...");
    progressDialog.show();

    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    Call<UserResponse> call = service.userLogin(email, password);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {


       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
                finish();

            }
                 else {

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == buttonSignIn) {
        userSignIn();
    }
}
}
```

heres php script im using slim to do the api and mysqli

```
$app->post('/login', function ($resquest, $reponse, $args) use ($app) {

require_once ('dbconnect.php');

$email = $_POST['email'];

$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT `email` ,`password` FROM `Users` WHERE `email` =  '" . $email . "'  AND  `password` =  '" . $password . "'   ";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $response = array(
     'error'=>"0",
     "message" => "nice"
     );

} else {

    $response = array(
     'error'=>"1",
     'message'=>"fail"
     );
}

return $this->response->withJson($response);

  });
```

Comment: What are you getting in your response if credentials are wrong?

Comment: $response = array(
   'error'=>"1",
   "message" => "fail"
   );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

1. From PHP respond 200 OK for successful login and 401 Unauthorized for invalid email or password.

   ```
   if($login_failed){
       header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
       exit;
   }
   ```
2. From PHP send some message for successful login and some different message for unsuccessful login. Then read the response from Android, compare strings and act accordingly.

   ```
   if($login_failed){
       echo("failed");
   } else {
       echo("success");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

i need to compare the value from db and macth it

```
     if (response.body().getMessage().equals("nice")) {

               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
                finish();

            }
```